# How to concat letters to a sequencing number as a Datatype for a postgres database

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, pg

I am using Postgres with an Express Server I am trying to place some characters before an integer number to a Primary key.

So I have a table called `users` For every row I want to to grab the first three letters then have an incrementing number added to the end of it seperated by a space or (a dash) so the end result I want the rows to look like this for the Primary Key column.

```
use-1
use-2
use-3
ETC..
```

I have made a sequence

```
    const userSequence = `
        CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS user_seq
        INCREMENT 1;
    `
```

I am trying to make use of the concat function with the sequence when I try to make the table I am getting this error

`error: syntax error at or near "concat"`

So here is the table I am trying to create

```
    const users = `
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id TEXT NOT NULL concat('use', '-', nextval('user_seq')::text) PRIMARY KEY,
            email varchar(50) UNIQUE,      
            password text NOT NULL,
            is_admin boolean,
            first_name varchar(50),
            last_name varchar(50)
        );
    `
```

It is giving me the error on the concat function. Where am I going wrong with it?

Comment: 1) Why? 2) You know `sequences` are not guaranteed to be gapless? 3) `use-` is a constant so why not just a `sequence` directly and then add `use-` on retrieval? 4) You are missing `DEFAULT` before `concat ...`.

Comment: I managed to fix it i changed to concat_ws but you are right I was missing DEFAULT
So I did
id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT concat_ws(' ', 'use', nextval('user_seq')),

Comment: better to have a serial as primary key an concat it when needed a integer id will be faster when joining than a text

Comment: I recommend solving it with a `view` or just *render* a `serial` id with a prefix of `'use-'` in the presentation layer.